# sparklyr- is calling print or glimpse on a spark data frame an expensive operation? how is it performed?

Tags: apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I'm trying to understand the lazy evaluation in `sparklyr` and have found some behaviour which I'm not sure is intended.

I have a large table with 10 billion rows called 'records', let's say.

```
dat <- tbl(sc, 'records')
```

What exactly happens under the hood when I type the following commands:

```
dat
print (dat) 
glimpse(dat)
```

I would have expected, since none of these commands actually return information about the full number of rows, that there to be a clever method that only gathers ten or so rows and prints those. I would also expect this to be super fast as well and generally independent of the size of the table.

When I actually run these commands on my large table, it pretty much just does nothing. After monitoring the back end a bit, it appears that spark is trying to gather the entire table together. 
When I do the same thing on smaller tables with, say, only 10 000 rows. the result of the above commands will take about a minute or so.

I find this behaviour surprising - is there some documentation that I am missing? Am I thinking about this the wrong way or is my set up wrongly configured?

Thanks, any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gathers ten or so rows (...) I would also expect this to be super fast as well and generally independent of the size of the table.

This is not a justified expectation. It might be true in some very specific cases (no restrictions on the data, no wide transformations upstream, uniform data distribution, distribution-friendly input format, cache), but in general case, execution time, will be highly dependent on the overall execution plan.

Overall:

- "Wide transformations" like aggregations or distinct will cause evaluation of a whole dataset, with exception to sorting with limit (for reasonably low number of rows).
- Highly restrictive selections (`filter`) will cause evaluation of all partitions in the worst case scenario (typically if required number of rows cannot be collected from the first few partitions).
- Any input format which doesn't guarantee proper data distribution (like gzipped files or default JDBC connectors) will evaluate more data than it is required to produce the output.

Comment: i have found that i can `select * from records limit 10` quite quickly. does that imply that I should be able to `print(dat)` and it works return quickly? if not, is there another command i can run to inspect my spark data frame faster?